# Writing Coverage Filter in Planet API

Tags: python, planet

I am in the process of building a script for my degree capstone project with the use of arcpy and the Planet API module.

Currently it takes a GeoJSON created from a simple spatial join and in turn downloads the required area before cropping and then segmented and classified through the image analysis software eCognition (this last part is not scripted and just uses the Cognitive Neural Network we have developed.

All my parameters are working as expected but I am having trouble with the coverage of the area. I cannot seem to find any information on how to search for 100% of a required area. Some results come back unaffected but others either have partial or totally missing scenes. Below is the script I am using.

```
#set GEOJSON location
GEOJ = "D:\\Planet_Download\\GeoJSON\\TWP0630804.json"

#open GEOJSON file
with open(GEOJ) as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())
for feature in data['features']:
    poly_type = feature['geometry']['type']
    coords = feature['geometry']['coordinates']
    geojson_geometry=feature['geometry']
geometry_filter = {
    "type": "GeometryFilter",
    "field_name": "geometry",
    "config": geojson_geometry
}

from planet.api import filters
from datetime import datetime

#set date variables. June to July = most green months
start_date = datetime(year=2018, month=6, day=1)
end_date = datetime(year=2018, month=7, day=31)

date_filter = filters.date_range("acquired", gte=start_date, lte=end_date)
#cloud cover less than 1%
cloud_filter = filters.range_filter("cloud_cover", lte=0.01)
#set requirments togther
and_filter = filters.and_filter(date_filter, cloud_filter, geometry_filter)

#add required platform
item_types = ["REOrthoTile"]
req = filters.build_search_request(and_filter, item_types)
print req
print ""

#open quick search
res = client.quick_search(req)
```

I am relatively new to Python and scripting so I am not sure if there is an alternative method I could use to receive the total required area or if there is a known process to achieve 100% coverage through the Planet API.

Comment: There might be something unintended in the `for feature in data['features']` block of your code. This will create a filter using the *last* feature in the GeoJSON file. If there's only one feature, then no problem, but otherwise this might not do what you expect.

Comment: Is this one feature as in the GeoJSON polygon or as in the last coordinate? I will only be using one GeoJSON file per use of the script as that is the way it is being incorporated with the other tasks of the script.

Comment: It'll take the last *polygon* in the set of features. One GeoJSON file can contain many polygons, so this could lead to unexpected results. For example, this GeoJSON contains two polygons, but your script will only search for imagery over the second one: https://gist.github.com/bosth/3e35f925f7fc56312814b68a96dde13b

Comment: Ah noted! could well be the problems I was having then.
I've also been having tremendous trouble in loading the shapely module for the code you offered with getting around the full coverage problem. Even when python is saying it is loaded already I cannot import it, so it looks like I will not be able to incorporate that part. I don't suppose there is another way around this at all? Once again, thank you for all your help!

Comment: I'm afraid getting Shapely set up is going to be different for every operating system so my Linux instructions likely won't translate to Windows. That being said, you can try `pip install shapely` and see what happens.

Comment: I thought as much, I currently get the message;

Requirement already satisfied: shapely in c:\python27\arcgis~1.6\lib\site-packages

But when I try to run anything with shapely I get;
 
OSError: Could not find lib geos_c.dll or load any of its variants ['C:\\Python27\\ArcGISx6410.6\\Library\\lib\\geos_c.dll'].    

Even though I have (I think) successfully loaded the GEOS module, I just cannot find or seem to download the c.dII portion.

Unfortunately my deadline is fast approaching so I may have to just leave this portion out, a shame but I'm still happy so far.

Comment: hi @bosth sorry to be a bother again. With the 'for feature in data['features']' block, how do I get around that problem? if I remove the [] section it throws up a 'string indicies must be intergers' error. Or is there a way that I can incorporate something like 'togeojson foo.kml' which will allow me to get around the problem?

Comment: You'll need to decide how to handle the case where there are multiple features per file. It could be enough for you  to change indentation so that the search is done in each loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Planet's Data API only allows you to test for *intersection* with a geometry. It doesn't let you test for a complete coverage of that geometry by an image footprint.

One way you could do this is to test the footprints to see if they contain your area of interest on the client side.

For example, you can add the following to the end of your code to do additional filtering on the results in `res`:

```
from shapely import geometry

aoi = geometry.shape(geojson_geometry)
for item in res.items_iter(100): # check the 100 most recent images
  g = geometry.shape(item["geometry"])
  if g.contains(aoi):
    print item["id"]
```

This will just print the ID of the matching items, but you can edit the last line to download the images or do something else instead.

Note that orthotiles follow a fixed grid, so if your AOI crosses the grid boundaries, you will *never* see any results.

Comment: Thank you, should I put this in at the end of the script I already have so it incorporates the other filters too or is this not a problem in the way it will work?

I'm currently having some problems loading shapely, command line with wheel doesn't seem to work either, but once I figure that out I will give it a go for sure.

Comment: Yes, it goes right at the end. This takes the quick search results in `res` and does an additional filtering so that you end up with just IDs that fully cover your AOI.

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much for your help you've given with this script over the last few days. I think with this running it does everything I need, now just to incorporate my arcpy script with it. Is there a way you would like me to cite your work or is there another way I can show my appreciation?

Comment: If this is an academic work, you can use the Planet citation found at the bottom of the page here: https://developers.planet.com/docs/api/. You are also encouraged to share any interesting results with other users on our Communities page: https://support.planet.com/hc/en-us/community/topics.

Comment: I had already incorporated this in the full body of the script and have actually spoken to a planet employee about the work being written in the planet blog. I will write a full version in the community in the coming weeks as due date is rapidly approaching. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the coordinates for each item and calculate how much of area of interest in covered by a particular item. I am using Shapely and Proj to do that in the following code block. Once I know which items I would like to download I use Planet's clip and ship API to only download the clipped areas.

```
from planet import api
import os
import json
import time
from shapely.geometry import shape, GeometryCollection, Polygon
from pyproj import Proj
import requests
from tqdm import tqdm
import zipfile

PLANET_API_KEY = os.environ.get("PLANET_API_KEY")
pclient = api.ClientV1(PLANET_API_KEY)

with open('Aoi.geojson') as f:
    geojson = json.load(f)

for feature in geojson['features']:
    aoi_geo = feature['geometry']


# In[28]:


# Add Area of Interest GeoJSON to GeometryFilter
geometry_filter = api.filters.geom_filter(aoi_geo, "geometry")

# Set date filter to get images acquired within a specific date range
date_filter = api.filters.date_range("acquired",gte = "2019-05-01T00:00:00.001Z",lte = "2019-07-30T00:00:00.000Z")

# Clear filter. In this example we are filtering for images with greater than 90% clear
clear_filter = api.filters.range_filter("clear_percent", gte=60)

#combine all filters
filter = api.filters.and_filter(geometry_filter,date_filter, clear_filter)


item_types = ['PSOrthoTile']
asset_types = ['visual']

request = api.filters.build_search_request(filter, item_types)

# This will cause an exception if there are any API related errors
results = pclient.quick_search(request)

# Calculate AoI coverage in items in request. Need to clean this up to use meta-data
pa = Proj("+proj=aea +lat_1=37.0 +lat_2=41.0 +lat_0=39.0 +lon_0=-106.55")
lon, lat = zip(*aoi_geo['coordinates'][0])
x, y = pa(lon, lat)
cop = {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [zip(x, y)]}
s_aoi = Polygon(shape(cop))

img_id = []

for i in results.items_iter(1000):
#   Transform the pair from (lat1, lon1) to (lat1, lat 2, ..latn) (lon1, lon2,...lonn) 
    try:
        lon, lat = zip(*i['geometry']['coordinates'][0])
    except ValueError:
        lon, lat = zip(*i['geometry']['coordinates'][0][0])

    x, y = pa(lon, lat)
    cop = {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [zip(x, y)]}
    img = Polygon(shape(cop)) 
    img = img.buffer(0)
    intersection_co = s_aoi.intersection(img)
    img_id.append((i['id'],i['properties']['item_type'])) if (intersection_co.area/s_aoi.area) > 0.90 else False
    if (intersection_co.area/s_aoi.area) > 0.90:
        print(i['id'], i['properties']['item_type'], img.area/1000000.0, intersection_co.area/1000000.0, intersection_co.area/s_aoi.area)


# In[32]:


# Create target Directory if don't exist
dirName = 'aoi_clips'
if not os.path.exists(dirName):
    os.mkdir(dirName)
    print("Directory " , dirName ,  " Created ")
else:    
    print("Directory " , dirName ,  " already exists")


# In[33]:


def clip_payload(aoi_geo, item_id, item_type, asset_type):
    clip_payload = {
        'aoi': aoi_geo,
        'targets': [
          {
            'item_id': item_id,
            'item_type': item_type,
            'asset_type': asset_type
          }
        ]
    }
    return clip_payload


# In[34]:


def clip_request(clip_payload, api_key):
    # Request clip of scene (This will take some time to complete)
    request = requests.post('https://api.planet.com/compute/ops/clips/v1', auth=(api_key, ''), json=clip_payload)
    clip_url = request.json()['_links']['_self']

    # Poll API to monitor clip status. Once finished, download and upzip the scene
    clip_succeeded = False
    while not clip_succeeded:

        # Poll API
        check_state_request = requests.get(clip_url, auth=(api_key, ''))

        # If clipping process succeeded , we are done
        if check_state_request.json()['state'] == 'succeeded':
            clip_download_url = check_state_request.json()['_links']['results'][0]
            clip_succeeded = True
            print("Clip of scene succeeded and is ready to download") 

        # Still activating. Wait 1 second and check again.
        else:
            print("...Still waiting for clipping to complete...")
            time.sleep(30)

    return clip_download_url


# In[35]:


def download_clip(clip_url , scene_id):
    response = requests.get(clip_url, stream=True)
    with open('lb_port_clips/' + scene_id + '.zip', "wb") as handle:
        for data in tqdm(response.iter_content()):
            handle.write(data)

    # Unzip file
    ziped_item = zipfile.ZipFile('lb_port_clips/' + scene_id + '.zip')
    ziped_item.extractall('lb_port_clips/' + scene_id)    

    # Delete zip file
    os.remove('lb_port_clips/' + scene_id + '.zip')
    print('Downloaded clips located in: lb_port_clips')



# In[36]:


for img in img_id:
    for asset in asset_types:
        clip_url = clip_request(clip_payload(aoi_geo,img[0],img[1],asset), PLANET_API_KEY)
        download_clip(clip_url, img[0])


# In[34]:


for img in img_id:
    assets =  pclient.get_assets_by_id(id=img[0], item_type = img[1]).get()
    for asset in sorted(assets.keys()):
        if asset in asset_types:
            st = assets.get(asset)

            if st['status'] == 'active':
                print(img[0] + " Asset " + asset + " is active and ready to download")
                callback = api.write_to_file(directory='lb_port_ortho/')
                body = pclient.download(assets[asset], callback=callback)

            else: 
                print(img[0] + " " + asset + " is not activated, activating now")
                asset_activated = False
                activation = pclient.activate(assets[asset])
                time.sleep(120)

                while asset_activated == False:
                    assets_i =  pclient.get_assets_by_id(id=img[0], item_type = img[1]).get()
                    st = assets_i.get(asset)

                    if st['status'] == 'active':
                        asset_activated = True
                        print(img[0] + " Asset " + asset + " is active and ready to download")
                        callback = api.write_to_file(directory='lb_port_ortho/')
                        body = pclient.download(assets_i[asset], callback=callback)

                    else:
                        print("Waiting for activation of " + img[0] + " " + asset)
```